# Making a list (or iterable) of variables refer to the variables [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, iterable

Is there a way in Python (preferably 3.6 +) to make a list made from variables to refer the variables themselves, and not their values?

An example:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
l = [a, b, c]
print(l)
# Outputs: [1, 2, 3]
# I want: [a, b, c]
# Not preferred but acceptable: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Is this even possible? I'm using python 3.8.

In response to the comments: Any iterable is acceptable. I actually have a similar question on how to delete a variable given it's name as a string, but that's a topic for another question. This does relate to that though, so I decided to check if it was possible.

Comment: No it's not possible, use a container

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @mozway could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Codeman it's better that **you** provide a use case for what you want to achieve. Would a dictionary work? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, variables are internally [stored in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319607/how-are-variables-names-stored-and-mapped-internally?answertab=active#tab-top). Through these dictionaries, you can access and delete variables by giving their names as strings. Example:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for name in names:
    print(globals()[name])

print(a)
del globals()['a']
print(a) # a has been removed
```

Use `globals()` for global variables, `locals()` for local variables or `object.__dict__` for object members.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what your use case is, but a dictionary might be a good fit:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# or 
# l = list(d.keys())
```

Comment: This could work, but I do need to do things with `a`, like passing it to functions. Guess I'll do `d['a']` then, if there's no other way. Thanks!

Comment: This seems the most reasonable and pythonic